# What am I not escaping correctly?

Tags: string, vb6, escaping, syntax-error

I am trying to create a html file out of a database, and I have problems escaping this line `"<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />"`

Full code:

```vb6
Dim filer As Integer, paths As String
filer = FreeFile

paths = App.Path + "\DB"
Open paths + "\test.html" For Output As #filer
    '...
    Print #filer, "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />"
    '...
Close #filer
```

I don't know why it appears in red and don't let me create the `.exe` to even run it

Comment: Why not use single quotes instead?
"<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to escape double quotes the same as you would in perl or c++.

Try using the crazy MS double double quotes.
Like so:

```vb
Print #filer, "<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=UTF-8"" />"
```

OR

```vb
str1 = "<meta http-equiv=" & chr(34) & "Content-Type" & chr(34) ' etc
Print #filer, str1
```

**EDIT**: 
Corrected Quotes.

- Two Quotes= 1 quote character within a string.  This can be confusing when your quote character is right next to the quotes defining your string.

  - `"hello "" BOB"` = `Hello " Bob`
  - `"""Hello "" BOB"""` = `"Hello " BOB"`

Comment: are you sure `"""`? the dup link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103140/escaping-quotes-in-a-string-in-vb6 example only have two `""`, but there is also a guy who said `"""` I am confused now

Comment: Sorry, two is correct, I'll edit

Comment: The `Chr()` method isn't normally recommended as it's runtime evaluated rather than a compile time literal.

Comment: @Deanna - Great point.  Thanks for the edit as well.