# Passing strings

Tags: vba, excel

I need this excel statement to be executed in VBA

```
IF(AND(X2="FMS",O2>=0),1,0)
```

This is how I call my sub in VBA where I pass the varible "FMS"

```
Call passFunction("FMS")
```

Declaration of the Sub as follows

```
Sub passFunction(var As Variant) 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(X2=" & var & ",O2>=0),1,0)"
End Sub
```

However after the function gets executed, this is the output I get in Excel

`IF(AND(X2=FMS,O2>=0),1,0)`

Notice the quotes missing for the the variable FMS

Comment: do you want to stick this as text or formula? because it seems like you're missing a `=` sign before `IF...`. Also, do you want to insert the double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
wksheet.range("A1").Formula = 
"=IF(AND(X2=" & Chr(34) & var & Chr(34) & "," & Range("O2").Address & ">=0),1,0)"
```

**Update**

If var can be `Integer` then start with this line

```
var = IIf(VarType(var) = vbString, Chr(34) & CStr(var) & Chr(34), CLng(var))
```

and modify the above line to

```
 wksheet.range("A1").Formula = 
"=IF(AND(X2=" & var & "," & Range("O2").Address & ">=0),1,0)"
```

This will work if we want to compare to the integer as well. If we want to throw an error if it is an integer, then we can do

```
var = IIf(VarType(var) = vbString, CVErr, CLng(var))
```

If it can be anything else other than integer then we generalize this to

```
Select Case VarType(var)
    case vbString
        var=Chr(34) & CStr(var) & Chr(34)
    case vbLong, vbInteger
        var=CLng(var) ' Or CVErr depending on what we want to do
    case else
        var=CVErr
End Select
```

before the formula.

**Notes:**

- The last case makes the `var` as `N/A` and will throw an error
- Even the type `Integer` in `VBA` is internally casted to `Long`. So it is better to use `Long` in the first place.

Comment: var can sometimes be an Integer. I am trying to add this logic `var1 = var 
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(cmprVal1) Then var1 = Chr(34) & cmprVal1 & Chr(34) End If wksheet.range("A1").Formula = "=IF(AND(X2=" & var1 & "," & Range("O2").Address & ">=0),1,0)"` 

This logic doesnt seem to work

Comment: I tried your logic. Still doesnt work.


`Sub test()
    Call passFunction("FMS")
End Sub

Sub passFunction(var As Variant)
     Select Case VarType(var)
        Case vbString
            var = CStr(var)
        Case vbLong, vbInteger
            var = CLng(var)
    End Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").Formula = "=IF(AND(X2=" & var & ",O2>=0),1,0)"
End Sub`

Comment: Oh I see, you have removed the `Chr(34)` part. OK, I updated the code below update. Now when `var` is a string, it is wrapped in `""`. Could you clarify how you would like the `Sub` to act when it finds an integer? Does it need to make the comparison, throw an error, or just escape?

Comment: Works now after I add
`var = Chr(34) & CStr(var) & Chr(34)`
If it is an integer, just escape.. Do nothing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually passing quotes, you are using a string and passing in: FMS

[Escaping quotes in a string in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103140/escaping-quotes-in-a-string-in-vb6)

You can use "" to insert a quote into a string e.g: (from link)

```
dim sometext as String = "Hello ""Frank"" how are you?"
```

So you want:

```
Call passFunction("""FMS""")
```

Or you change passFunction to add the quotes in there:

```
Sub passFunction(var As Variant) 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "IF(AND(X2=""" & var & """,O2>=0),1,0)"
End Sub
```

Comment: This wont work for me. The var can be an integer sometimes, that is the reason I declare it as a variant

Comment: Then unless you want to check the type and handle things differently - you can use: Call passFunction("""FMS""")

Answer (score 1):

You `PassFunction` should be

```
Sub PassFunction(var As String)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(AND(X2=""" & var & """,O2>=0),1,0)"
End Sub
```

Remove the `=` from before `If` unless you do not want it to be calculated.

You can escape the double quotes in a string by wrapping the quotes with another double quote.

Also, if you are passing a String Variable than change the parameter type to `String`. Strings are faster than Variant.

Comment: thanks and +1 to you too. Pretty much the same thing so its worth saying that `chr(34)` is equivalent to `"` in VBA

Comment: This wont work for me. The var can be an integer sometimes, that is the reason I declare it as a variant