# Splitting symbol " using split function

Tags: vba, split

How do I use the `Split` function to split the `"`symbol from a string?

For example

> Hai".

I want to split the symbol `"` from this. This is the code I have so far:

```
Split(inputstring,""")
```

This is throwing compile error list separator or ).

Comment: Try Split(inputstring,"""") http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103140/escaping-quotes-in-a-string-in-vb6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap double quotes with another double quotes inside a String to escape the quote :)

```
Sub SplitQuotes()

    Range("A1") = "this is ""sparta!"

    Dim str As String

    str = Range("A1")

    Debug.Print "STR IS: " & str

    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(str, """")

    Dim item As Variant

    Debug.Print "#### now iterating through the array"
    For Each item In arr
        Debug.Print item
    Next

End Sub
```

output

[image]

---

or this `arr = Split(str, """")` could be replaced with `arr = Split(str, chr(34))` as `Chr(34)` returns a double quote`"`

Comment: + 1 I always preferred using `chr(34)` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes only if you don't confuse 34 with 32 like I do all the time heheh