# excel vba Split funtion using " as delimiter

Tags: excel, delimiter, vba

Is there a way to use " as delimiter?
As the function requires the following makeup: Split(String,"delimiter")
Placing the " sing between " brackets will give """ which results in an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `VBA.Split(yourString, Chr(34))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `"` using a double `""` character in order to use it between string literals. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103140/escaping-quotes-in-a-string-in-vb6)

Try it like this:

```
Split(String,"""")
```

Comment: Weet ik, maar moest eerst 5 minute wachten, je was te snel ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried four quotes, like this """"?