# in select statement how we compare a string field which contain single quotes

Tags: vb6

i have a filed in stock table with title product. when i use the following statement

> rs.Open  "select * from stock where product='" & product_name & "'
>   ",db,2,1
>
> id = rs!sub_head_id
>
> rs.Close

where product_name is string variable which contain a product name

for example:

> product_name="alpha's cell"

this  statement make an error, because of single quotes in string.
how we resolve this

note: i am using vb6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping quotes in a string in VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103140/escaping-quotes-in-a-string-in-vb6)

Comment: Can you just remove the quotes? There are many functions to trim or remove characters from a string in vb6.

Comment: my product id is in number format . but bno is in string format and some bno contain round braces like bno=(K009)

Answer (score 0):

Use this and try:

rs.Open "select * from stock where product='" & replace(product_name,"'","''") & "' ",db,2,1

Answer (score 0):

Ok , my problem is solved . some one suggest that set the Index of Criteria field like bno and productid .