# MySQL Escape characters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, special-characters

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to replace a special character with another in SQL (MySQL syntax). I've already tried with REPLACE function without success. What I would like to do is:

**From this string:**

```
"C:\foo\bar\file.txt"
```

**Obtain this string:**

```
"C:\\foo\\bar\\file.txt"
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. The literal answer is: `SELECT REPLACE('C:\\foo\\bar\\file.txt', '\\', '\\\\');`. Can you explain a bit further why you would want to do that? That's not typically something one does in the database, and it's likely you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Hello, i'm writing a function to export a pdf stored in a database. The problem is that many users will the use the wrong syntax, for example C:\mydirectory\myfile. MySQL require a path like "C:\\mydirectory\\myfile, with double backsashes. I want to format the input to this function in order to avoid syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought - this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). MySQL does not require anything from the path. What it does require though is its input to be syntactical. In input, the string literal interprets the sequences of backslash and another character as "escape", which removes special meaning from the next character. Since backslash is such a special character, it can be escaped to remove its special significance: one writes `\\` to get a string with a single backslash.

What this means is, if you write `'C:\\foo\\bar\\file.txt'` in an SQL command, MySQL will understand it as the string `'C:\foo\bar\file.txt'` (like in my comment under your question). If you write `'C:\foo\bar\file.txt'`, MySQL will understand the backslash as removing the special significance from letters `f`, `b` and `f` (not that they had any in the first place), and the string it will end up with will be `'C:foobarfile.txt'`.

Once the string is inside MySQL, it is correct, no replacements are necessary. Thus, you cannot use MySQL's `REPLACE` to prepare the string for input to MySQL - it is way too late for this. It is kind of like punching the baby in the stomach to pre-chew its food after it has already eaten it, it doesn't work that way and it hurts the baby.

Rather than that, use the language that you use to interface with the database (you didn't tag it, so I can't give you the details) to properly handle the strings. Many languages have functions that will correctly escape strings for you for use by MySQL. Even better, learn about prepared statements and parametrised queries, which completely remove the need for explicit escaping.

The best reference on parametrised queries I can recommend, with remedies for multiple languages, is [the Bobby Tables site](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: The problem is that i have (not my choise) to connect the database to excel. I suppose that the language to interface the database will be excel VBA and i don't know if it's possible to do such a task with that language.

Comment: Ugh. I must say I know next-to-nothing about Excel VBA. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103176/240443) makes any sense to you. If not, probably something like `REPLACE(REPLACE(str, "'", "''"), "\\", "\\\\")` in VBA (not in MySQL!) should be enough. If I haven't messed up the syntax.

Comment: I literally know nothing about excel VBA. I'm coding the DB side of this project, another person will be selected to implement the excel part. I'm trying to code as much as i can in the database side to simplify the job for the next person.

Comment: @Juri Then don’t worry about it, just assume everything that hits the database is correct, and if it’s not, the blame’s on whoever talks to the database.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE function should do the job for you - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html.

How are you passing the string into REPLACE function?

Comment: Hello, the string i'm passing to the function is something like:
"C:\foo\bar\file.pdf"

Comment: In that case you'll have to format the String before passing it to the SQL. The moment something like "C:\foo\bar\file.pdf" gets passed to REPLACE, it will treat \ as escape character.

Comment: @Juri What is the exact use case, you want to store the data into database or fetching from the database?

Comment: The execute case that i had in mind was something similar to:

select myfunction("C:\foo\bar\file.txt");

And i want that call to return "C:\\foo\\bar\\file.txt". But it seems that it's not possible to implement in the database side as suggested by Amadan.

Comment: @Juri Ok. Yes, that makes sense, the responsibility has to be on the caller of the function.